# «Мало-немало» — как пишется?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, раздельно-дефис

Как, скажите, правильно?

*— У него мало долларов.

— **Мало-немало**, а тратит он их — что, по-моему, самое главное, честно говоря, — очень-таки по-умному.*

Или так: ***мало немало***?
Или так: ***мало не мало***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***Мало не мало**, а тратит он их – что, по-моему, самое главное, честно говоря, – очень-таки по-умному*.  (В текстах встречается интонационное тире, не дефис.)

Правило  **[§ 16. Запятая при повторяющихся словах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=104#pp104)**

4. Запятая не ставится:

1. между двумя **повторяющимися словами**, из которых второе употреблено с отрицанием **не**, если сочетание этих слов образует смысловое целое, выражающее **неполное отрицание или неопределенность в обозначении чего-либо**: Страшно не страшно, а на душе как-то строго (Леск.); Дождь не дождь, а паши (Ш.); На нём надето что-то круглое: сюртук не сюртук, пальто не пальто, фрак не фрак, а что-то среднее (С.‑Щ.); Рад не рад, корми его (П.); Попал в стаю, лай не лай, а хвостом виляй (Ч.); Маленький не маленький, а это знать не мешает; Была не была — пойду;

**Примеры**

Ю. М. Нагибин. Остров любви (1972-1979)

— **Мало не мало**, а вчинили… — пробормотал Тредиаковский, и лицо его налилось кровью.

А. Н. Островский. Горячее сердце (1869)

[Наркис (муж, приказчик Курослепова (по дому))] **Мало не мало,** а коли есть мое такое желание, так, значит, подавай: разговаривать нечего.

Александра Маринина. За все надо платить (1995)

– Ну, **мало – не мало**, а результат налицо, – вздохнул Гордеев. (Интонационное **тире**.)

Answer (score 0):

Мало не мало / или / мало - не мало ~ мало - много.

Но меня больше заинтересовало: у него *мало долларов*.

Это криво, потому что "**долларов мало**", со счетными объектами мало ставится после слова. Перед словом *мало* идет когда речь о действиях, процессах, степени воздействия или явлении: мало бегает, мало света. Иногда можно сказать "мало морозов" ~ "мало морозило", чтобы не делать морозы счетным. Также можно употребить перед прилагательными *мало красивых людей*, но - *людей мало*.

Долларов мало, но - мало долларовых купюр.

Также можно провести такой эксперимент:

У него долларов - мало, а волос - много.

У него мало - долларов. - совсем иначе звучит, криво, что имеется ввиду? У него мало красных долларов?

У него мало: долларов, волос, рук, - так норм.